# Service located on network

Tags: wcf, web-services, domain-name-system, ip, hosts

I've got a WCF web service that handles a portion of business logic and data access. This service is hosted on a server on our network at our office. Our website, hosted elsewhere, uses this service and believes it to be located at http://thatservice.somedomain.com.

I've also got a Winforms app used (only) on machines on our network that wishes to consume the  same service. What I'd like to do is have the local machines attempt to consume the service at http://thatservice.somedomain.com without having a dependency on our internet connection.

I believe I could do this by editing everyone's hosts file to point http://thatservice.somedomain.com to the server's internal static IP address, but I don't think that's the way to go. Is this something I can do in our internal DNS server? Is there some better way to handle this altogether?

Comment: @razlebe - I did think of that, however I half expected the contributors here to come back with "No, no, no. You should do it this way..." from a software architecture point of view.

Answer (score 2):

Despite this not being the place for it, the solution I ended up implementing is:

I created a Zone in my network's DNS for somedomain.com and pointed thatservice.somedomain.com to the internal IP of the service, but had to also duplicate all of the DNS records that exist on somedomain.com publicly.